# Какой алгоритм лучше всего использовать для поиска в тексте?

Tags: apache, php, java, c++, mysql

Какой алгоритм лучше всего использовать для поиска в тексте?

Для примера возьмем php MySQL.

Конструкция `like`, как показывает опыт, - полная хрень для поиска, когда речь идет о большой посещаемости и большом количестве информации.

Что посоветуете?
Есть литература или ссылки - кидайте, пригодится все.

Comment: в первую очередь вопрос о высоко посещаемом сайте с огромной текстовой базой и нужно искать слова либо предложения по тексту

Answer (score 5):

Лучше всего - смотреть в сторону готовых поисковых движков. А если хочется самому изобрести очередной велосипед, то начать с того, что поиск ведётся не по контенту, а по отдельному массиву информации, который строится, например, так:

1. слова со страницы приводятся к единой форме (существительные - им. пад, ед. число etc)
2. заносятся в базу с указанием дополнительной информации (например, порядковый номер слова на странице, сама страница, изначальная словоформа, какими тегами окружено - всё, что может понадобиться)
3. ...

Дальше - работаем с поисковым запросом. Самый простой вариант: одно слово. Приводим его к той же словоформе, как в пункте 1, ищем. Находится - не забываем выдать исходный фрагмент (для этого и сохраняем "оригинальные" версии слов, их порядок...). Нужно искать несколько слов или работать с языком запросов - продолжаем морщить лоб, но к этому времени или идея писать свой движок умрёт сама собой, или ответы на возникающие вопросы уже будут получены :)

Ну и организацией этого хранилища должен заниматься отдельный движок. Или совсем отдельный, который периодически обходит страницы, смотрит на изменения и строит присковый индекс (Яндекс.Сайт etc). Или обновление поискового индекса происходит при создании/редактировании страницы, простейший вариант реализован в движках многих форумов.

Как-то так, в самых общих чертах, без подробностей :) Так что - см. первое предложение первого абзаца.

Answer (score 3):

Sphinx с периодической индексацией информации по cron..  Других нормальных вариантов пока не придумали..
Eсть еще Lucene, но оно для Java

Comment: http://sphinxsearch.com/

Answer (score 2):

Php для такой задачи не очень подходит, для морды веб проекта-да. Тут еще смотря как поиск происходить будет - просто по файловой системе или по бд. Вам сказали, что есть много движков так пользуйтесь ими. Есть еще nutch, solr. Это тяжеловесы. Очень хорошие штуки. Я бы на вашем месте использовал java, в ней много чего есть для работы с интернетом.

Answer (score 0):

Аналоговая корреляция.